# Playing a list of songs in combobox one by one in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a list of songs in a combobox. I am playing the song based on the selection if user. Here is my code.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wplayer.controls.pause();
        song = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        index1 = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        pictureBox4.Image=Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\Input\\zeneszek.gif");
        pictureBox4.SizeMode=PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox4.Visible=true;
         wplayer.PlayStateChange += new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(wplayer_PlayStateChange);
        wplayer.URL = Application.StartupPath + "\\Input\\" + song + ".mp3";
        wplayer.controls.play();
        WMPLib.WMPPlayState playstate = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded;
        label4.Text = "Playing" + song;
    }
 public void wplayer_PlayStateChange(int newstate)
        {
            if (newstate == (int)WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
            {
                playstate = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded;
                song = comboBox1.Items[index1++].ToString();
}
}
```

After the end of the song I wanted to play the next song which is the next one in the combobox selection. Can someone help on this? I tried playstate change event also. Still I am not able to play the next song. I increased the index of the combobox when the play state is wmppsMediaEnded. When do I need to play that song? I tried playing the song when the state is wmppsStopped and wmmppsTransitioning but in both the cases I am able to play only two songs continuously. after the end of the 2nd song I am not able to play the remaining.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PlayStateChangeEvent to check for newstate showing that the media has ended, then move the selectedindex + 1 and play the new song.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This also might be some help to you: http://stereoclood.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SteroMood/MediaPlayers/WmpMediaPlayer.cs